# Sending formdata from front-end to back end using Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

i am trying to send an https request from my front-end(react js) to my back-end (nodejs) using axios.This https request has a csv file converted in formData.My code for sending teh request  is this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.state.selectedFiles);     //selectedFiles is input from a ui form

  const {data : QueryResult} = await axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: "https://localhost:3000/...",formData,
              headers: {'x-observatory-auth': localStorage.getItem("token")},  
              });
             }
```

I process this in back end using :

```
function AddSessions(req,res){
      let stream = fs.createReadStream("./upload_folder/upload_file.csv");
      let csvData = [];

      let csvStream = fastcsv
          .parse()
          .on('error', function(error) {
              res.status(400).send("Incorrect Data format.Please enter a csv file");
              return
          })
          .on("data", function(data) {
            csvData.push(data);
          })
          .on("end", function() {
              // remove the first line: header
              csvData.shift();

              let insert_query = "INSERT IGNORE  INTO Sessions(SessionID, StationID,PointID, Username, VehicleID, connectionTime,"+
              " doneCharginTime, Timezone ,KwhDelivered ,Protocol,Payment )  VALUES ?";
              db.query(insert_query, [csvData], (err, db_res) => {
                  if (err) {
                      res.status(400).send("Incorrect Data format for  Sessions or File is too big(larger than 1GB)")
                      console.log(err)}
                  else{
                      let count_query = "SELECT Count(*) as count FROM Sessions";
                      db.query(count_query, (err1, result) => {
                          if (err1) res.send(err1.message)
                          else {
                              res.status(200).send({SessionsInUploadedFile :db_res.affectedRows +  db_res.warningCount , SessionsImported : db_res.affectedRows, TotalSessionsInDatabase :result[0].count});


                        }
                    })
                }
            });

        }

        );
    stream.pipe(csvStream);
  }
}
module.exports = AddSessions
```

The error i get is :

```
 code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT IGNORE  INTO Sessions(SessionID, StationID,PointID, Username, VehicleID, connectionTime, doneCharginTime, Timezone ,KwhDelivered ,Protocol,Payment )  VALUES '
```

and i can't seem to understand what i am doing wrong.

Note that using postman this request can be done fine.I've been stuck in this for way too long and i can;t find a solution so any help would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please recheck your insert query or generate raw sql and check manully